# get initialState value in reducer from action inRedux

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, reduce

I am new in redux, I created a initialState in reducer.jsx like that:

```
const initState = {
  loading: false,
  todos: [],
  todo: null,
};
```

Then in action.jsx, I want to use the value 'todo' of initState. How can I do that. I try to use useSelector but it is impossible because useSelector cannot be used in action

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn redux-toolkit. It's a lot easier to learn than redux and createSlice api in redux-toolkit is what you find right now.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice

Comment: I will try redux-toolkit later, but I want to use Redux core in this project :(

Answer (score 0):

First of Create store using redux then install react-redux library for state management with react. follow code below step by step.

Step - 1

```js
// redux.js
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

Step - 2

```js
// rootReducer.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import todosReducer from './todosReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 todos: todosReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Step - 3

```js
// todosReducer.js

const initState = {
  loading: false,
  todos: [],
  todo: null,
};

const todosReducer = (state = initState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'add_todo': {
      return [
        ...state,
        action.payload.todo
      ]
    }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Step - 4

```js
//todosAction.js
 export const addTodo = (todo) =>  {
    
   return({
        type:'add_todo',
        payload: {
            todo 
        }
    })
};
```

Step - 5

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';
import store from '../store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
     </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

you can avoid file path choose yourself. import correct file path.

Step - 5

```js
// Todos.js
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {addTodo } from './todosActions';


const Todos = () => {
    const { todos } = useSelector(state => state.todos);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("todos", todos); // show all todos state
    } ,[])
  
   const todo = {
     id: 1,
     title: "redux is state management library"
   }

  const todoHandler = () => {
    dispatch( addTodo(todo));
  }
    return(
      <div>
       // Todos Here
       <button onClick={todoHandler}> add todo </button>
      </div>
   );

}
```